# Android using Bar Graph View Alphabet

Tags: android, graph

I have a program android use graph view but default label graph view using int number like 1, 2 or 3. I wanna change the label from 1, 2, 3 to A, B, C horizontal label like this http://prntscr.com/bwxclx

My code like this

```
GraphView bar_graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> bar_series = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 0),
            new DataPoint(1, 7), // 1st war
            new DataPoint(1.5, 0),
            new DataPoint(2, 5), // 2nd war
            new DataPoint(2.5, 0),
            new DataPoint(3, 8), // 3rd war
            new DataPoint(3.5, 0),
            new DataPoint(4, 0)
    });
```

Anyone can help me how to change label 1, 2, 3 to A, B, C

Answer (score 0):

You can set labels statically using StaticLabelsFormatter().

In my case below, the "plotArrayX" is an array containing the values I want. They can be text, numbers or empty.

I've used it to generate timestamps set at.

The code below is kotlin, but it's quite simlar to java.

```
val staticLabelsFormatter = StaticLabelsFormatter(graph)
staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(plotArrayX)
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter)
```

my actual X axis datapoints are just an incremented integer. The labels are then automatically exchanged with the static ones in the final view.